# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol public

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, lnk2019

I'm trying to write my code in Visual Studio 2013 for second time in CodeBlocks, I am getting an error while trying to arrange a Binary Search Tree,
here is my code for
BinarySearchTree.h

```
#pragma once
template <typename T>
class BinarySearchTree{
private:
    struct Node{
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        T data;
    };
    Node *root;
public:
    BinarySearchTree();
    bool isEmptyTree() const;
    void insertInBinarySearchTree(T& value);
    void removeFromBinarySearchTree(T& value);
    void printBinarySearchTree();
    void inorderBinarySearchTree(Node *p);
};
```

Here is BinarySearchTree:

```
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree(){
    root = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::insertInBinarySearchTree(T& value){
    Node *t = new Node;
    Node *parent;
    t->data = value;
    t->left = nullptr;
    t->right = nullptr;
    parent = nullptr;
    if (isEmptyTree()) root = t;
    else{
        Node *currentNode;
        currentNode = root;
        while (currentNode){
            parent = currentNode;
            if (t->data, currentNode->data) currentNode = currentNode->right;
            else currentNode = currentNode->left;
        }
        if (t->data < parent->data) parent->left = t;
        else parent->right = t;
    }
}
template <typename T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::removeFromBinarySearchTree(T& value){
    bool isElementFound = false;
    if (isEmptyTree()){
        cout << "This tree is empty!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    Node *currentNode;
    Node *parent;
    currentNode = parent;
    while (currentNode != nullptr){
        if (currentNode->data == value){
            isElementFound = true;
            break;
        }
        else{
            parent = currentNode;
            if (value > currentNode->data) currentNode = currentNode->right;
            else currentNode = currentNode->left;
        }
    }
    if (!isElementFound()){
        cout << "Data not found in tree!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    if ((currentNode->left == nullptr && currentNode->right != nullptr) || (currentNode->left != nullptr && currentNode->right == nullptr)){
        if (currentNode->left = nullptr && currentNode->right != nullptr){
            if (parent->left == currentNode){
                parent->left = currentNode->right;
                delete currentNode;
            }
            else{
                parent->right = currentNode->right;
                delete currentNode;
            }
        }
        else{
            if (parent->left == currentNode){
                parent->left = currentNode->left;
                delete currentNode;
            }
            else{
                parent->right = currentNode->left;
                delete currentNode;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    if (currentNode->left == nullptr && current->right == nullptr){
        if (parent->left == currentNode) parent->left == nullptr;
        else parent->right == nullptr;
        delete currentNode;
        return;
    }
    if (currentNode->left == nullptr && currentNode->right == nullptr){
        Node *checker;
        checker = currentNode->right;
        if ((checker->left == nulptr) && (checker->right == nullptr)){
            currentNode = checker;
            delete checker;
            currentNode->right = nullptr;
        }
        else{
            if ((currentNode->right)->left != nullptr){
                Node *leftCurrentNode;
                Node *leftCurrentNodeParent;
                leftCurrentNodeParent = currentNode->right;
                leftCurrentNode = (currentNode->right)->left;
                while (leftCurrentNode->left != nullptr){
                    leftCurrentNode = leftCurrentNodeParent;
                    leftCurrentNode = leftCurrentNode->left;
                }
                currentNode->data = leftCurrentNode->data;
                delete leftCurrentNode;
                leftCurrentNodeParent->left = nullptr;
            }
            else{
                Node *temporaryNode;
                temporaryNode = currentNode->right;
                currentNode->data = temporaryNode->data;
                currentNode->right = temporaryNode->right;
                delete temporaryNode;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
template <typename T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::printBinarySearchTree(){
    inorderBinarySearchTree(root);
}
template <typename T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::inorderBinarySearchTree(Node *p){
    if (p != nullptr){
        if (p->left) inorderBinarySearchTree(p->left);
        cout << " " << p->data << " ";
        if (p->right) inorderBinarySearchTree(p->right);
    }
    return;
}
template <typename T>
bool BinarySearchTree<T>::isEmptyTree() const{
    return root == nullptr;
}
```

And finally main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree<int> BST;
    int ch, tmp, tmp1;
    while (1)
    {
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << " Binary Search Tree Operations " << endl;
        cout << " ----------------------------- " << endl;
        cout << " 1. Insertion/Creation " << endl;
        cout << " 2. Removal " << endl;
        cout << " 3. Print " << endl;
        cout << " 4. Exit " << endl;
        cout << " Enter your choice : ";
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1: cout << " Enter Number to be inserted : ";
            cin >> tmp;
            BST.insertInBinarySearchTree(tmp);
            break;
        case 2: cout << " Enter data to be deleted : ";
            cin >> tmp1;
            BST.removeFromBinarySearchTree(tmp1);
            break;
        case 3: cout << endl;
            cout << " Print tree " << endl;
            cout << " -------------------" << endl;
            BST.printBinarySearchTree();
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I found this error to be responsible for missing implementation, but I can't find function without implementation.

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting? It's hard to help without it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the functions in the header file

> "The only portable way of using templates at the moment is to implement them in header files by using inline functions."

https://books.google.co.il/books?id=n9VEG2Gp5pkC&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=%22The+only+portable+way+of+using+templates+at+the+moment+is+to+implement+them+in+header+files+by+using+inline+functions.%22&source=bl&ots=Ref8pl8dPX&sig=t4K5gvxtBblpcujNxodpwMfei8I&hl=en&ei=qkR6TvbiGojE0AHq4IzqAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q=%22The%20only%20portable%20way%20of%20using%20templates%20at%20the%20moment%20is%20to%20implement%20them%20in%20header%20files%20by%20using%20inline%20functions.%22&f=false

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that in `main.cpp`, you instantiated your class using `int` as the template, so in the header file everything is treated as int. E.g. `void insertInBinarySearchTree( int& value );`

However, in the implementation file, the functions are still defined using the more general template definition, and on compile-time `main.cpp` is going to be looking for a function definition for

`void insertInBinarySearchTree( int& value );`

where it fails because in the cpp file you only have

`void insertInBinarySearchTree( T& value );`.

In order to fix this, simply go to the very last line of your cpp and add the following:

`template class BinarySearchTree<int>;`

And the problem will be fixed as a definition has been added that takes care of ints.

P.S: Looking through your code, it looks like `=` and `==` were being used incorrectly. Remember that `=` is for assignment and `==` is for checking whether two values are the same. There were many others errors as well, so I fixed the ones that I noticed [here](http://pastebin.com/LgPYK6Mc).